# Use specific data out of a realm query result. (in swift)

Tags: swift, realm

I have an class defined called Overuren (realm database)

```
class Overuren: Object {

    @objc dynamic var dagCode: String?
    @objc dynamic var type: String?
    @objc dynamic var keuzeGU: String?
    @objc dynamic var keuzeOT: String?
    @objc dynamic var code: String?
    var compGU = RealmOptional<Int>()
    var betGU = RealmOptional<Int>()
    var compOT = RealmOptional<Int>()
    var betOT = RealmOptional<Int>()
    var transport = RealmOptional<Int>()
    var travelCO = RealmOptional<Int>()

}
```

I want to look up a single value in a query result but that doesn't work because I always get all the components in my result.
I've tried a lot of code to get out the one I need but nothing works.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import iOSDropDown

class IngaveOverurenViewController: UIViewController {
    var dagDatabase: Results<Overuren>?

    @IBOutlet weak var datumOvertime: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var typeOvertime: DropDown!
    @IBOutlet weak var urenOvertime: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var keuzeGU: DropDown!
    @IBOutlet weak var keuzeOT: DropDown!

    let feestDagen = ["Jan 1, 2020","Apr 13, 2020","May 1, 2020","May 21, 2020","Jun 1, 2020","Jul 21, 2020","Aug 15, 2020","Nov 1, 2020","Nov 11, 2020","Dec 25, 2020"]

    var dagIndex = Int()
    var dagBenaming = String()
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // code om de datepicker popup op te roepen
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.date
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged(sender: )), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        datumOvertime.inputView = datePicker
        // ...

        // code om de dropdownmenu's op te vullen
        typeOvertime.optionArray = ["CallOut","CallOut Wacht","Gepland","Ongepland"]
        keuzeGU.optionArray = ["Betalen","Verletten"]
        keuzeOT.optionArray = ["Betalen","Verletten"]
        // we zetten nu de waardes in de dropdownmenu's
    }

    @objc func datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium
        formatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none
        datumOvertime.text = formatter.string(from: sender.date)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        view.endEditing(true)
        dagWeek()
    }

    @IBAction func drukOpKnopje(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let realm = try! Realm()

        if dagIndex == 1 {
            dagBenaming = "Zondag"
        } else {
            if dagIndex == 7 {
                dagBenaming = "Zaterdag"
            } else {
                dagBenaming = "Weekdag"
            }
        }
        print(dagIndex)
        print(dagBenaming)
        print(typeOvertime.text as Any)

        dagDatabase = realm.objects(Overuren.self).filter("dagCode = %@ AND type = %@ AND keuzeGU = %@ AND keuzeOT = %@", dagBenaming,  typeOvertime.text as Any, keuzeGU.text as Any, keuzeOT.text as Any)
        print(dagDatabase)
    }

    func dagWeek () {
        print(datumOvertime.text)

        if  feestDagen.contains(datumOvertime.text!) {
            dagIndex = 1
        } else {
            dagIndex = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: datePicker.date)
            // dagIndex = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: datePicker.date)
            // this returns an Int
        }

        print(dagIndex)
        // zondag is 1
    }
}
```

The line I use for the result =

```
dagDatabase = realm.objects(Overuren.self).filter("dagCode = %@ AND type = %@ AND keuzeGU = %@ AND keuzeOT = %@", dagBenaming,  typeOvertime.text as Any, keuzeGU.text as Any, keuzeOT.text as Any)
```

And the result is :

```
Optional(Results<Overuren> <0x7fb75603c520> (
    [0] Overuren {
        dagCode = Weekdag;
        type = CallOut;
        keuzeGU = Betalen;
        keuzeOT = Betalen;
        code = OPB10;
        compGU = 0;
        betGU = 100;
        compOT = 0;
        betOT = 100;
        transport = 2;
        travelCO = 1;
    }
```

But what I need is only OPB10 after code=
And later I wan't to make some calculations with the numbers after the last 6 components.

my realm file looks like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkX0J.jpg)

Comment: Realm doesn't fetch individual properties. It fetches a set of objects. If you only need a single property then just leave the other properties alone.

Comment: Since Realm is an object database (unlike NoSQL) it retreives objects. What is your expected output and as per @RobertCrabtree suggestion, can you just ignore the other properties?

Comment: @RobertCrabtree thanks for the answer, I understand that it fetches a set of objects, but I don't understand or find a way to use just the one I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your asking how to access a property of a Realm object (?)

Here's your code that performs a query

```
dagDatabase = realm.objects(Overuren.self).filter(
"dagCode = %@ AND 
type = %@ AND 
keuzeGU = %@ AND 
keuzeOT = %@", 
dagBenaming,  typeOvertime.text as Any, keuzeGU.text as Any, keuzeOT.text as Any)
```

and as you mentioned it returns this object, and you're interested in the `code` property

```
Optional(Results<Overuren> <0x7fb75603c520> (
    [0] Overuren {
        dagCode = Weekdag;
        type = CallOut;
        code = OPB10;
        ...
```

When results are returned, they Results object contains the results of that query which could be nil, 0  or some number of objects. Results work very much like an array.

If you are just interested in the first object you can leverage the .first property, similar to an array.

```
let tagInfo = dagDatabase.first! //example. Dont use in production. Keep reading
```

then to access the property you want

```
let code = tagInfo.code // the code var will now contain OPB10
```

Note that ! used in the above Force Unwraps an optional and that's generally dangerous so here's one option

```
if let tagInfo = realm.objects(Overuren.self).filter("dagCode = %@ AND...).first {
   print(tagInfo.code)
}
```

as that will safely unwrap the optional in case it's nil and print the code.

Comment: What I've tried before was : let code = dagDatabase.code and that didn't work

Comment: @BDROOS Glad I could help!